# Why doesn't $x^4+14x^2+49$ reducible over $C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was following James Cook's Abstract Algebra at the moment, in his video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo8ogufaSKA&list=PLBY4G2o7DhF0JCgapYKrqibGaJuvV4Gkb&index=41 at $36:26$ he said that $x^4+14x^2+49$ is irreducible over $C$, I was confused. In $C[x]$, all the units are in C, but $f(x)=x^4+14x^2+49=(x^2+7)(x^2+7)=(x+\sqrt{7}i)(x^3-(\sqrt{7}i)x^2+7x-7\sqrt{7}i)=(x-\sqrt{7}i)(x^3+(\sqrt{7}i)x^2+7x+7\sqrt{7}i)$,

By the definition of the reducible I check all the factorisation of $f(x)$, but they all satisfy the definition:for all the factorisation $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, such that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ aren't units.

Comment: There are no (non-linear) irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb C$.  They all factor into linear terms

Comment: Nor does the speaker assert that it is irreducible.  Indeed, he writes out the factoring into two quadratics, which is already a factoring over $\mathbb Q$.  His point appears to be to illustrate that you can have a reducible polynomial over a field that has no roots over that field.  This example works over $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$, though obviously not over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I misunderstand his idea!

Comment: Reducibility follows directly from $x^4+14x^2+49=(x^2+7)^2$, because $x^2+7$ is not a unit.

Answer (score -1):

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that any nth-degree polynomial has n roots when including complex numbers, so it will always be reducible over C since for any root r, the binomial x-r is a linear factor of the original polynomial.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).